# Converting txt file to adjacency list, then making Graph

Tags: java, text, java.util.scanner

I am doing a Breadth First Search program that will read in an adjacency list type text file, then perform BFS on it accordingly. I am having trouble reading in the text file, then adding it as an array list of nodes.

*How would I get it to correctly read each line and associate the connections for it?*

I have tested my program by manually adding Nodes within my main, then making a graph and performing BFS on it.

Here is my Node class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Node {

        public String data; // data element
        public boolean visited=false; // flag to track the already visited node
        public List<Node> adjacentNodes = new LinkedList<Node>(); // adjacency list
//      public List adjacentNodes = new LinkedList(); // adjacency list
        public Node rootNode;

        public Node(String data){
            this.data = data;
        }

        public void addAdjacentNode(final Node node){
            adjacentNodes.add(node);
            node.adjacentNodes.add(this);
//          adjacentNodes.add(rootNode);
//          node.adjacentNodes.add(this)
        }

    }
```

And here is my Graph class: (Where I attempted to read in my text file is within my main)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.*;


/*- enqueue the start node to a Queue
- make the start node as visited
- while queue is not empty
  - dequeue the node lets say u
  - print or whatever you want to
  - for every adjacent node v of u
      - if v is not already visited
          - mark v as visited
          - enqueue v to the Queue*/
public class Graph {

    public List nodes = new ArrayList();

    public void breadthFirstTraversal(Node rootNode){
        Queue<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
//      Queue q = new LinkedList();
        q.add(rootNode);
        System.out.print(rootNode.data + " ");
//      printNode(rootNode);
        rootNode.visited=true;
        while(!q.isEmpty()){
            Node n = (Node)q.poll();
            System.out.print(n.data + " ");
            for(Node adj : n.adjacentNodes){
                if(!adj.visited){
                    adj.visited=true;
                    q.add(adj);
                }
            }
            clearNodes();
        }

    }

    private void clearNodes() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nodes = null;   //clear nodes and set to null
    }

/*  private void printNode(Node node) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print(node);
    }*/

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        Graph g = new Graph();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Connections.txt"));   // scanner to read file
        String line = scan.nextLine();                        // read first line
        int nbLine = Integer.parseInt(line);                  // get number of lines
        ArrayList<int[]> al = new ArrayList<int[]>();        
        for(int i = 0; i < nbLine; i++) {                     // read each line
           line = scan.nextLine();
           String[] token = line.split(" ");                  // split each number into different String
           int[] points = new int[token.length - 1];          // prepare array of int[] - 1
//         int[] point = new int[];
           int[] point = new int[token.length];
        for(int j = 0; j < token.length; j++){              // skip first one
             points[j-1] = Integer.parseInt(token[j]);       // store as int
           al.add(points);                                    // save in ArrayList
        }


/*      Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/cantuj3/Documents/Ass 2/Connections.txt"));
        ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
        while (s.hasNext()){
            g.nodes.add(s.next());
            //list.add(g);
        }       
        s.close();*/



/*      Node frankfurt = new Node("frankfurt");
        Node mannheim = new Node("mannheim");
        Node wurzburg = new Node("wurzburg");
        Node stuttgard = new Node("stuttgard");
        Node kassel = new Node("kassel");
        Node karlsruhe = new Node("karlsruhe");
        Node erfurt = new Node("erfurt");
        Node numberg = new Node("numberg");
        Node augsburg = new Node("augsburg");
        Node munchen = new Node("munchen");

        Graph g = new Graph();

        g.nodes.add(frankfurt);
        g.nodes.add(mannheim);
        g.nodes.add(wurzburg);
        g.nodes.add(stuttgard);
        g.nodes.add(kassel);
        g.nodes.add(karlsruhe);
        g.nodes.add(erfurt);
        g.nodes.add(numberg);
        g.nodes.add(augsburg);
        g.nodes.add(munchen);

        frankfurt.addAdjacentNode(mannheim);
        frankfurt.addAdjacentNode(wurzburg);
        frankfurt.addAdjacentNode(kassel);

        mannheim.addAdjacentNode(karlsruhe);

        karlsruhe.addAdjacentNode(augsburg);

        augsburg.addAdjacentNode(munchen);

        munchen.addAdjacentNode(kassel);
        munchen.addAdjacentNode(numberg);

        wurzburg.addAdjacentNode(erfurt);
        wurzburg.addAdjacentNode(numberg);

        numberg.addAdjacentNode(stuttgard);
        g.breadthFirstTraversal(frankfurt);*/
    }

}
```

**Here is my input file:**

```
01 02
02 01 03
03 02 04 05
04 03
05 03 06
06 05
```

Here is that chunk of code I wrote in my main by itself:

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Connections.txt"));   // scanner to read file
        String line = scan.nextLine();                        // read first line
        int nbLine = Integer.parseInt(line);                  // get number of lines
        ArrayList<int[]> al = new ArrayList<int[]>();        
        for(int i = 0; i < nbLine; i++) {                     // read each line
           line = scan.nextLine();
           String[] token = line.split(" ");                  // split each number into different String
           int[] points = new int[token.length - 1];          // prepare array of int[] - 1
//         int[] point = new int[];
           int[] point;
        for(int j = 0; j < token.length; j++){              // skip first one
             points[j-1] = Integer.parseInt(token[j]);       // store as int
           al.add(points);                                    // save in ArrayList
        }
```

**Am I on the right track?**

Comment: What does the input file look like? What have you tried so far and what specific issues are you running in to? How does the actual behavior differ from the expected behavior?

Comment: @JasonC I updated my code and added the input file,as well as a chunk of code I wrote trying it out, having problems with one line though as described above

Comment: Update! I got rid of that error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic steps will need to be:

1. Read a line of the file
2. Turn that line into an object
3. Add that object to a collection
4. Repeat until you have no more lines to read

Since I don't want to do your work for you, I'll leave you with some samples:

**Read a line of the file**

```
String line = reader.readLine(); // in this case, 'reader' will be a BufferedReader referencing your file
```

**Turn that line into an object**

This depends on what your input file format looks like. As an example, if my input is something like this:

```
first_thing 10
second_thing 20
third_thing 30
...
```

then I could do:

```
String[] components = line.split(" ");
if (components.length == 2) {
    MyCustomObject myCustomObject = new MyCustomObject(components[0], components[1]);
}
```

**Add that object to a collection**

```
String[] components = line.split(" ");
if (components.length == 2) {
    MyCustomObject myCustomObject = new MyCustomObject(components[0], components[1]);
    myCollection.add(myCustomObject); // you can choose the type of collection here
}
```

**Repeat until you have no more lines to read**

```
while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I updated my code and added some code from what understanding I have gotten online, could you have a look?